# Dojo: javascript execution in page loaded via ajax

Tags: ajax, dojo

I have a template loaded via ajax and template contains the following lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    alert('11');

</script>
```

But I don't see neither alert window not any errors. Maybe the thing is in request and response Content-type headers? Mine are following:

Response Headers:

```
Content-Type    text/html
```

Request Headers:

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded

X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is: I loaded that template via contentPane.

The moral: use dojox.layout.ContentPane istead of dijit.layout.ContentPane.

Comment: also of note  is the `executeScripts` attribute of the dojox.layout.ContentPane which tells the ContentPane to go through its content and look for <script> tags to execute.

Comment: I didn't touch it, it must be true by default?

Comment: it is on by default, I just figured it would be worth noting that the `executeScripts` property is what controls that behavior.